# Min-height property in percents doesn't work

Tags: html, css

This is how basically document looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="content_holder">
<div class='all_links'>
</div>
  <div class="item">
        <div class="notice"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom_nav">
</div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    }

body{
overflow-y:scroll;
min-width: 1024px;
}

#content_holder{
    min-height: 100%;
}

.item {
width: 800px;
position: relative;
top: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -400px;
text-align: center;
min-height: 100%;
```

}

The problem that on this specific page `html, body, .item` properties about min-height doesn't work in percents.

On other pages everything is OK. Parent of `.item` is body. I can't get what is wrong here.
When I check height with Chrome Dev Tool, body height on this page is 360px, which, of course, twice less than it shoudl be.

Why?

**UPD**: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnqjT/)

What I've found out, that height property doesn't work specifically for `#content_holder`, and works for body

Comment: It would help if you made a jsFiddle for this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's very confusing question.

Comment: Please make an example on http://jsfiddle.net. That would be very very helpful.

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto, what do you mean confusing? Any hints how I can improve this question?

Comment: What do you want from that web page?

Comment: set min-height: 100px;  height: 0; on the parent

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-glitter-vv3g2

Answer (score 2):

When `height` is set on any element in a percentage, it's immediate parent element must have `height` specified (not as a percentage, but in `px` or `em`).

The weird exception to that rule is the `<html>` element, which if it is given `height: 100%`, an immediate child element can then have `height` as a percentage (i.e. the `<body>` element).

As for setting `min-height: 100%`, this sets the initial size to 100% height and allows the element to exceed that height.

I'm pretty sure that `min-height` also follows the same above-mentioned rule for `height` -- for any element set with `min-height` in a percentage, its' immediate parent element must have `height` specified (not as a percentage), with the exception of the `<html>` element being set with `height` as a percentage.

However, if an element sets `height` as a `px` or `em` value, and its' immediate child element sets `height` as a percentage, the grandchild element's `height` can be set as a percentage, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Just change `min-height: 100%` to `height: 100%`.

The height of your webpage will be 100% of the browser screen, or 100% of the content height, whichever is bigger.

Comment: yes, but if content is actually more than 100% height?

Comment: Body is 100% w/h by default. I see no reason having this in css.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted, but whole issue was to set body and html to 100%, and min-height of #content_holder to 100%

Comment: Just found this and setting `body html { height:100%; }` did the trick.